# How to add java script to the from user control button click event to parent page

Tags: javascript, c#

a link will generate in a user control button click event, i want to use clientscipt.registerstartupscript add javascript to open this link in a new window. but won't work.

if same code in this user control parent page, it will work, so question is can i somehow add script to parent page and execute it.

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("<script type = 'text/javascript'>");
sb.Append("window.open('");
sb.Append(uri.AbsoluteUri);
sb.Append("');");
sb.Append("</script>");

ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "script", sb.ToString());
```

Comment: Are you showing any errors in your console? (most likely an error with `ToString`)

Answer (score 0):

Please change `sb.ToString()` to `sb.toString()`. Case matters.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is indicate the page. Let's say page1 has a user control controlA, controlA has a button and in button click event a script need to add to page1 page_load, just use

page1.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(page1.GetType(), "script", sb.ToString());